# Get exact dimensions of resized image using Sharp

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, sharp

I have a Cloud Function that resizes an image uploaded to Cloud Storage using Sharp. Everything works, but I'm trying to find a way for Sharp to include metadata of the exact height and width of the new image. I could make a new function that uses other npm packages to download the image from the url and get what I want, but I'm curious to know if there is a way for Sharp to do that as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just include "withMetadata()"

```
sharp('input.jpg')
  .withMetadata()
  .toFile('output-with-metadata.jpg')
  .then(info => { ... });
```

you can find the documentation here
https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/api-output#withmetadata

Comment: Perfect! Not sure how I missed this from the docs but it's what I need, thanks!